# Threads produce same random number?

Tags: c, multithreading, random, pthreads

I am trying to produce random numbers for each thread to use, but all the threads produce the same number.

The number changes when I run my program each time, but all the threads produce the same number for a given run.

What should I do to produce different random numbers for each thread?

```
void *Customer(void *customer_id)
{
    unsigned int iseed = (unsigned int)time(NULL);
    srand (iseed);
    int rastgele = rand() % 3 + 1;
    int *id_ptr,customer_idd;
    id_ptr=(int *) customer_id;
    customer_idd=*id_ptr;

    printf("This is thread : %d  %d \n",customer_idd,rastgele);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Don't seed in the thread.

Comment: in multiple-thread  time() might give same value..s evey thread Initial random number generator with same value...

Comment: time seeding on generation == not random at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `rand` for pseudo random generation in connection with threads. This function uses a shared state that is common to all threads. This creates dependencies between the PRN drawn by the threads and slows down substantially since the access to the state must be mutexted.

Alternatives on POSIX systems would be `nrand48` and `jrand48` that receive a state (that should be thread specific) as their argument. As others said, seeding that state just with a time value is not a good idea, threads may do that at the same moment.

Answer (score 6):

Seeding the random number generator with the time will give you the same random number if the threads produce a random number at the same second. You could just seed with the time plus the thread number or something like that.

Or, as Dave suggested, you could just seed once outside the thread.